# TypeScript How to access field in promise method

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to access field in promise method.

Here is the code:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
export class User{
  
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
  constructor(){
    this.firstName = "Tom";
    this.lastName = "Jack";
    this.getName = this.getName.bind(this);
  } 
  getName():Promise<string>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      return resolve(`My Name is ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`);
    }) ;
  }
}

export class UserApi{
  userName:string;
  getUserName():string{
    let user = new User();
    user.getName().then(name => {
      return name;
    });
    return '';
  }
  
}
// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;
let user = new UserApi();
appDiv.append('This is ' + user.getUserName());
```

`user.getUserName()` returns empty.

How to get the expected string from promise method?

In other words, how to access `this` in Promise method?

Update:

**I don't have issue with return value from Promise, please pay attention to how to access class property or value from class method which is return `Promise`.**

Comment: why do you actually use a `Promise` here?

Comment: @Antoni This is just a demo, `getName()` will be a method which send request or any other operations.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How it works? I want to access `this.firstName` in Promise method `getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a promise from the getUserName method. Like this:

```
getUserName(){
    let user = new User();
    return user.getName().then(name => {
        return name;
    });
}
```

And if you’re just going to return the name like above, you don’t need the “then”:

```
return user.getName();
```

When you use the getUserName method you need to deal with the promise. Like so:

```
let user = new UserApi();
user.getUserName().then((name) => {
    appDiv.append('This is ' + name);
});
```

Comment: for your code, `getUserName` will throw error.

Comment: Sorry about that. What error?

Comment: check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1avren)

Comment: Yeah. Fix the return type of getUserName and update the usage on the last line and it should work

Comment: it returns expected result, I am wondering whether there is any way to avoid `user.getUserName().then`?

Comment: Ok, cool. I don’t think it’s possible. Asynchronous calls will always require you to use Promises all the way to the caller. You could perhaps use async/await syntax to make the code look nicer, but I’m not sure if it’s supported everywhere.